# Why is it better to call the ResourceManager class as opposed to loading resources directly by name?

Tags: c#, resourcemanager

I was working on localizing a large project, and I was doing that by creating a large resource file manually, and calling each string by name in the code. Instead of calling the `ResourceManager` and using `GetString` (for dialog boxes, etc), I was simply replacing each string by `Resources.ClassName_MethodName_StringName`.

I have a feeling I'm supposed to be using the `ResourceManager`, but I want to understand why it's better before I change all of my code to use it.

Comment: No, you *are* supposed to go via Properties.Resources.NameOfStringResource. You're doing it right. That's why the Resources.Designer.cs is created for you.

Comment: for example, in Razor, ressources are "strongly typed". That is you can use RessourceName.StringName instead of RessourManager.GetString("StringName"). An intelisense helps you.

Comment: Well it's good to know I don't have to go back and change anything. MSDN says to call ResourceManager for everything, so that's why I thought I was going about it incorrectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there's no reason to use the ResourceManager directly (some exceptions to that will apply), because if you use generated code from the resx-Files all it does is the following:

```
public static string MyResourceName {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("MyResourceName", resourceCulture);
    }
}
```

This is great, since you get Compile-Time validation of your resource-names for free!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prvn_131971/chapter-i-resources-and-localization/

> Internally, the generated class uses an instance of the
>   ResourceManager class, which is defined in the System.Resources
>   namespace. The instance of this class is accessible through the
>   generated class's ResourceManager property. **Internally, the property
>   procedures for accessing the embedded resources themselves are just
>   wrappers around calls of one of the GetXxx methods (that is, GetString
>   or GetStream) of this ResourceManager instance.** For example, the
>   resource that is accessible through the generated property procedure
>   Resources.MyResourceStrings.

So calling resources directly by name you're using YourResources.ResourceManager.GetString() method anyway.

Comment: Does this still work if you switch your resource provider to for example a DB ResourceProvider?