# Is it better to access directly resource.resx instead of ResourceManager?

Tags: c#, localization

I know two methods to get string from resource files.

Method 1: Directly access.

```
string str = _NAMESPACE.Properties.Resources.HelloWorld;
```

Method 2: Via ResourceManager.

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("_NAMESPACE.Properties.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
string str = rm.GetString("HelloWorld");
```

If there are multiple localizing resources files, both these two methods would get correct localizing string.

If I made a typing mistake in string key, method1 would fail while building.
Method2 will fail until run time. For this reason, I think method1 is better than method2.

I found some similar questions in this forum. However, I still can't get good answer for my question.

1. [Why is it better to call the ResourceManager class as opposed to loading resources directly by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502957/why-is-it-better-to-call-the-resourcemanager-class-as-opposed-to-loading-resourc)
2. [Need to use ResourceManager + GetString to support cultures OR I can just point directly at the resource file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246631/need-to-use-resourcemanager-getstring-to-support-cultures-or-i-can-just-point?rq=1)

Is method1 really better?

Comment: Look at all those hard-coded strings in the second code!  The first one is much more refactor-friendly.

Comment: If you wish to divide your resources among *multiple* resource files (e.g., `Properties.Messages`, `Properties.Icons`, etc.), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5246631/1497596) and its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the first method is better because when you use the second method you are creating a new instance of the resource manager which I would think is an unnecessary use of memory.

Edit*

After reading this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx

It seems they are basically the same, when accessing resources directly with the resources class, internally a resource manager class is used to create an instance of the object.

Comment: You're absolutely right that both use the `ResourceManager` class, but that doesn't negate your point about creating a new instance in snippet 2.  The first version creates one instance and reuses it as many times as necessary.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, thanks for the confirmation, this was my original train of thought and after thinking to hard on it I began to doubt myself.